# Static content caching Issue in POST method with Chrome

Tags: jsp, caching

Static content don't get cached in Chrome if make call using POST method.

For Example :

Test_1.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> Caching Test </TITLE>
<META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="EditPlus">
<META NAME="Author" CONTENT="">
<META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="">
<META NAME="Description" CONTENT="">
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<form method="POST" action="test_2.jsp">
 <input type="SUBMIT" value="OK"> 
</form> 
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

test_2.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> Caching Test </TITLE>
<META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="EditPlus">
<META NAME="Author" CONTENT="">
<META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="">
<META NAME="Description" CONTENT="">
</HEAD>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/caching.js"></script>
<BODY>
JS Caching...
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Here, Second time request send to server which return 304 for script file as it's not modified. As JavaScript file has already cached static content download request does not reach to server. It works fine in IE.

Can anyone please guide me on this?